quilt for both tent and hammock camping?
i want to buy a quilt that would serve me both for hammock camping as under quilt and for tent camping as top quilt.
it is granted that the under quilt has built-in attachment points to the hammock, however when used as top quilt, it should be able to be strapped to the pad.
Is that such?
Thanks!

If you have attachment points surely you can rig up some way of strapping it to your pad.

Just buy one that works for your hammock. IMO it's much harder to get that right than the tent/pad right. As Jon said, you can just rig up some way of strapping it to your pad. I personally use one made by Kammok. It works great with my hammok, and is fine as a trail quilt. It's not as good as the quilts made by enlightened equipment or feathered friends, but it's fine most of the time.
